# Particular output from a struct given offset in C

Tags: c, struct

The following code will print the values stored on each of the `Foo` structs. The issue I'm having is calculating where `i` and `j` should start given the value of `offset`, which it can vary. Items in `Foo` can vary as well. offset can go from 0 to total amount of values allocated. In this particular case `offset = 6`, so it should output this:

```
Bar: 0 - Foo: 6
Bar: 0 - Foo: 7
Bar: 0 - Foo: 8
Bar: 0 - Foo: 9

Bar: 1 - Foo: 0
Bar: 1 - Foo: 1
Bar: 1 - Foo: 2
Bar: 1 - Foo: 3
Bar: 1 - Foo: 4
...
```

but right now it outputs:

```
Bar: 1 - Foo: 1
Bar: 1 - Foo: 2
Bar: 1 - Foo: 3
Bar: 1 - Foo: 4

Bar: 2 - Foo: 2
Bar: 2 - Foo: 3
Bar: 2 - Foo: 4

Bar: 3 - Foo: 3
Bar: 3 - Foo: 4
....
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int val;
} Foo;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    Foo *foo;
} Bar;

#define MAX 10
int main () {
    Bar bar[MAX];
    int i, j;
    int arr[10]={10,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5};

    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        bar[i].size = arr[i];
        bar[i].foo = malloc (sizeof (Foo) * bar[i].size);
        for(j = 0; j < bar[i].size; j++) {
            bar[i].foo[j].val = j;
        }
    }

    int offset = 6;
    int init = offset / 5;
    for (i = init; i < MAX; i++) {
        for (j = i % 5; j < bar[i].size; j++) {
            printf("Bar: %d - Foo: %d\n", i,  bar[i].foo[j].val); 
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what are you asking for?

Comment: I'm looking for the right output. (such as the output above), right now it doesn't print it that way.

Comment: And what output do you get? Nobody here is going to look at fifty lines of code trying to figure out what the difference is between what your code DOES and what the expected behaviour is without at least a clue as to what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is right:

```
int init = offset / 5;
```

I don't think this is right either:

```
for (j = i % 5; j < bar[i].size; j++) {
```

If I understand the problem setting correctly, your number of eleements in each "bucket" (Foo object) can vary, and you should take into account how many there are when calculating the starting point, then count up from the starting point until you have printed ten items. This would only require a single loop.

Comment: You are right, those statements are the issue I'm having. The number of elements in each "bucket" can vary. `offset` can be seen also as the items that I don't want to display. i.e., `offset = 25` -> don't display the first 25 items.

Comment: Right, so assuming that `int arr[10]={10,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5};` isn't part of how the data structure MUST work, and that `int arr[10]={7,4,3,5,9,5,2,5,8,5};` is also valid, then you must basically "count until you reach the entry that is just before your offset, then calculate how far into it you need to go from that value. Your current code only works for an array that has EVERY element as 5, which is clearly wrong, since the first element is 10.

Comment: So I'm guessing I would need to add two more loops to calculate how far into it I need to go before outputting. Is that correct?

Comment: One loop to figure out your starting position, and one to actually to the printing. You will need to figure out, in that second loop, when to change the "outer" index and start at zero on the next "lump".